# Looking for examples where $u''''-u''+u=f$ and $u'(-1)=u'(1)=u(1)=u(-1)=0$ for some $f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a $u(x)$ and an $f$ that make the answer to $$u(x)''''-u(x)''+u(x)=f(x)$$ where $$u'(-1)=u'(1)=u(1)=u(-1)=0$$ reasonably short.

I have some numerical code I am trying to test but I can't seem to find a nice solution to this problem.

Comment: See [Characteristic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus)).

Comment: Couldn't you just use $u(x) = (x-1)^2 (x+1)^2$ and then calculate what $f$ would be?

Comment: Thank you. That does work well. I appreciate it. For some reason I couldn't think of that one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 
$$u(x)={{\cos{\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2}\right) }}^{2}}$$
then
$$f(x)=(\pi^4+\pi^2+1){{\cos{\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2}\right) }}^{2}}-\frac{\pi^4}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $u(t) = (t-1)^2 (t+1)^2$, then

$f(t) = 29 - 14 t^2 + t^4$

Seems "simple enough."

Here's the solution for $f(t) = 0$:

$$-\frac{c_1 e^{-\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2}} \sec \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\left(e^{2
   \sqrt{3}}-1\right) \left(e^{\sqrt{3} (t+1)}-1\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right)-\sqrt{3} \left(e^{2 \sqrt{3}}-e^{\sqrt{3} (t+1)}\right)
   \cos \left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right)+\sqrt{3} \left(e^{2 \sqrt{3}}-e^{\sqrt{3}
   (t+1)}\right) \cos \left(\frac{t+3}{2}\right)\right)}{1+e^{2 \sqrt{3}} \left(2
   \sqrt{3} \sin (1)-1\right)}$$

This is merely *one* example of a $u(t)$ and $f(t)$ that solves the equation.  I suspect that even this is not "reasonably short" according to the OP.  Given this solution, I suspect that finding other pairs will be rather difficult.

Of course other "solutions" are $u(t) = 0 = f(t)$.

Comment: Your edit to the question changed substantially the meaning of the title (which was indeed conflicting with the post). Furthermore,  your answer does not seems to be exactly what OP was asking for.

Comment: @rafa1111:  The OP originally stated in the title s/he wanted a solution for "all" $f(x)$, which is of course inappropriate.  S/he certainly didn't mean that, as is clear from the first sentence.  It was for this (obvious) reason I changed (and improved) the title.

Comment: IMHO, OP should've been asked about their intention; depending on their knowledge about ODE's, they could think that asking for a solution for generic $f(x)$ is reasonable.

Comment: There is no mathematical meaning to "generic."  Regardless, "generic" certainly does not mean "all" (as originally posted).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I apologize if my wording was confusing on this question. The $(x-1)^2(x+1)^2$ answer works well for me.